# Portable way to convert an unsigned value to its signed negation in C++14

Tags: c++14, unsigned, signed, integer-arithmetic

I'm looking for a portable C++ function that computes the mathematical function *f(x) = -x* where the input is unsigned and the output is signed.  The function should work for the full range of `long long` values and throw an exception if the input is out of range.  It should not rely on compiler support for an even bigger integer type to catch overflow.  Here are two working but undesirable functions that compute what I want:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <limits>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

long long
slow_negate(unsigned long long val)
{
  string s = '-' + to_string(val);
  errno = 0;
  long long r = strtoll(s.c_str(), nullptr, 10);
  if (errno)
    throw range_error("slow_convert overflow");
  return r;
}

constexpr long long
twos_complement_negate(unsigned long long val)
{
  constexpr long long minll = numeric_limits<long long>::min(),
                      maxll = numeric_limits<long long>::max();
  static_assert(minll == ~maxll && -(minll + 1) == maxll,
                "only works for two's complement arithmetic");
  return val > maxll + 1U ? throw range_error("twos_complement_negate overflow")
    : val >= 0 ? (unsigned long long) -val
    : (unsigned long long) (-val + 1) + 1;
}
```

The problem here is that the first function is obviously horribly slow and not a `constexpr` (which such a simple function really should be), while the second function makes additional assumptions about two's complement integer representation that are not guaranteed by the language spec.

It sounds like such an easy problem, but somehow I've been unable to come up with a good portable solution that works for every possible input.

Answer (score 0):

Did I miss something or why couldn't you just do

```
constexpr signed long long f(unsigned long long input) 
{
   return (input > static_cast<unsigned long long>(
       std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max()))
       ? throw std::range_error{ "overflow" } 
       : -static_cast<signed long long>(input);
}
```

or, more general

```
template<typename T>
constexpr auto f(T input) -> std::make_signed_t<T>
{
    using signed_t = std::make_signed_t<T>;
    return (input > static_cast<T>(std::numeric_limits<signed_t>::max()))
        ? throw std::range_error{ "overflow" } 
        : -static_cast<signed_t>(input);
}
```

Comment: On machines with two's complement arithmetic, your answer doesn't work for `std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max() + 1U` (which is the magnitude of a valid negative number).

Comment: @user3188445: So, you need to compare with `static_cast<unsigned long long>(std::numeric_limits<signed long long>::max()))+1U`

Comment: But wouldn't this cause trouble when converting to signed before negating it (last line), since it is not representable as a `signed long long`? One could, however, handle it as a separate case.

Comment: @SergeGoncharov That's essentially my second example (which I fixed), but it only works on machines that use two's compliment arithmetic.

Comment: @user3188445 The check for two's complement is in practice unnecessary, since there is no commercially available hardware that uses one's complement. That has only a historical interest, for example [UNIVAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UNIVAC_1100/2200_series) used it (and some series are still supported by Unisys).

Comment: @SergeGoncharov Then why doesn't the C++ spec require two's complement arithmetic?  If it's only of historical interest it seems weird that the language committee would leave the door open to other forms of arithmetic.  There's already enough undefined and unspecified behavior programmers have to worry about from real architectures and optimizations...